# Create UUID on client and save primary key with Django REST Framework and using a POST

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'd like to be able to create a `UUID` on the client and send it to *Django Rest Framework* (DRF) and use that for the `Primary Key` of the Model.

So far, when I send the `Primary Key`, which is labeled `id` in my source code, DRF ignores the `id` and uses the default argument of the Model to generate a fresh `UUID`.

However, when I test from the Model, using the normal Django ORM to create the object,  and pre-set the `UUID`, the Model accepts the `UUID` as it's `Primary Key` and doesn't try and recreate a new one.

Is this possible?

My stack is

- Django 1.8
- Django Rest Framework 3.1

Here is the code.

**serializers.py:**

```
class PersonCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Person(AbstractUser, BaseModel):
```

Comment: I have a related question and commented on github (for reference) https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2432

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `id` field of the serializer is set as [read-only](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields) because of the `editable=False` argument.

> Model fields which have editable=False set, and AutoField fields will
>   be set to read-only by default,

Try declaring it explicitly:

```
class PersonCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Explicit declaration sets the field to be `read_only=False`
    id = serializers.UUIDField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. Works like a charm!

Comment: Seconded. Also note that you can drop the `read_only=False` when declaring it explicitly, as the `read_only` keyword argument is `False` by default.