# Optional pk argument for CREATE in Django's DRF ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a regular ModelViewSet for one of my models, but I want to have the option to specify a specific PK to create a new instance. E.g. if I would post:

```
{
    "name": "Name"
}
```

It would get a random pk. But if I posted:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Name"
}
```

I want it to have the specified pk (id).

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687423/create-uuid-on-client-and-save-primary-key-with-django-rest-framework-and-using) person, what I did is adding the `id` field to my ModelSerializer like this:

```
class ConversationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    List all conversations, or create new / edit existing product.
    """
    queryset = Conversation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ConversationSerializer

class ConversationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(required=False)  # Instead of serializer.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Conversation
        fields = '__all__'
```

While this works for the `create` method, it causes issues for the `update` and `partial_update` ones, where `id` is now a required argument as a query string parameter and in the request body like this (from the docs):

```
update
PUT /conversations/{id}/
Update existing conversation.

Path Parameters
The following parameters should be included in the URL path.

Parameter       Description
id (required)   A unique value identifying this conversation.

Request Body
The request body should be a "application/json" encoded object, containing the following items.

Parameter       Description
id  
access_token    
username    
password    
app_user_id 
name
```

Having two params with the same name is bad practice, of course. E.g. when using `requests` and passing a parameter dictionary, it doesn't work anymore because it doesn't know which parameter I'm addressing.

How can I fix this such that the `id` parameter is only optional for the `create` method, but all other methods (list, read, ...) stay exactly the same as in the default case?

**My solution**

based on JPG's answer, I modified my serializer to this:

```
class ConversationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['view'].action == 'create':
            self.fields['id'] = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Conversation
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Which class are you using for Views ? ModelViewset?

Comment: Yes, ModelViewset. Added my view above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is possible by overriding the **`__init__()`** method of the serializer.

```
class ConversationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['view'].action == 'create':
            self.fields['id'] = serializers.CharField()
        else:
            self.fields['id'] = serializer.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Conversation
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I slightly adjusted your solution but this worked.